# Sticky fixed top menu, when we scroll

Tags: html, css

**How to position a top menu as fixed, such that when we scroll, the menu doesn't move?**

This doesn't work:

```css
body { overflow-y: scroll; }
#header { position:fixed; width:100%; height:50px; background-color:yellow; }
#container { padding-top: 60px; }
```

```html
<div id="header">Bonjour</div>
<div id="container">Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br>Blah<br></div>
```

Comment: What isn't working in your example? The #header is fixed to the top of the page.

Comment: @EricN : True: my question is non-sense. If flagged for deletion (mod action needed).

Answer (score 0):

When I unterstand you right this question solve the same problem. [Using jQuery to keep scrolling object within visible window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273453/using-jquery-to-keep-scrolling-object-within-visible-window)

Sorry for the short answer but I am only on my  iPad.

Comment: Eeer, although this may be a valid duplicate question (haven't verified it matches the OP's intent), the proper way to indicate it as such is by clicking "flag" under the question, and marking it as a duplicate. Please don't write an answer that only points to another Stack Overflow question! Thanks for your involvement in this site, though.

Comment: (Sorry, my question is a pure non-sense. To be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure I understand your request.

As I get it, your code is working pretty well. The main reason you don't see it, might be big screen (not enough to be scrolled to).

The value that you put on body `overflow-y: scroll` doesn't help you at all, as that's a default for the `<body>` tag.

Now, in order to force some scrolling in `body`, you need to set some `height` or `min-height` to it, which is at least longer than your browser window height.

**Example:**

```
body {
    min-height: 2000px;
}
```

Otherwise, the code that you wrote works fine to stick the `#header` to always be in that position.

Comment: (Sorry, my question is a pure non-sense. To be deleted.)

Comment: If you want to stick an element during the scroll, then it's not possible via CSS, as you have to do this via JS or jQuery events!